# JQuery Datepicker Set Value As Epoch Time

Tags: jquery, datepicker, epoch

I use a data picker like that:

```
$('#startTime').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd ');
```

However when I want to set it I have a [epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) value that comes from my server (milliseconds since the standard base time January 1, 1970) How can I do that when I set it like this it just shows a number instead of date as usual?

Comment: What server are you using ? why cant you format the date to the correct format ?

Comment: I am getting it from a REST URL and if I format it from my server and decide to change the date format I will have to change the server side code too. However if get it as epoch I can show it at different date formats at different clients.

Comment: see my answer - its possible using the UNIX timestamp ( ie MS since 01/01/1970 )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#startTime').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", '@');
```

`@` sets the format to UNIX timestamp -> http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
*Please note: This is in **milli**seconds, not seconds*

Comment: Just one thing not tobe confused for me. I use Java at my server side. Does getting Java date as long and epoch time are same? I mean one of them calculating seconds and other one milliseconds or same?

Comment: @kamaci same as my comment on your question really - what are you using to create the date /time .... add your code to your question then I can tell you

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function()
{
    $("input[type='text']")
        .datepicker({ dateFormat: '@' })
        .change( function(){ this.value = parseInt(this.value,10)/1000; });
});
```

this is what I did to get the seconds vs. ms from the datepicker

Comment: I chained them together, saving a select, and made it vanilla JS, which is more efficient :)